# Does this implementation of Redis Connection Pool seem correct?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, redis, stackexchange.redis

I implemented a version of Redis Connection Pool manager (built on top of others' work) that is instantiated by a (client) static method in a static class. Currently, I am facing tons of connectionException errors in AWS.

I am concerned that the connection pool may not be working as intended. Therefore, I am asking for a code review of RedisCacheConnectionPoolManager implementation to identify any obvious problems with it. Thanks in advance.

```
public class RedisCacheConnectionPoolManager : IRedisCacheConnectionPoolManager
{
    private static ConcurrentBag<Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>> _connections;
    private readonly ConfigurationOptions _configurationOptions;
    private readonly int _poolSize;
    private const int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10000;
    private const int MIN_CONNECTIONS = 1;

    private bool _disposed = false;

    public RedisCacheConnectionPoolManager(int poolSize, string connectionString) : this(poolSize, ConfigurationOptions.Parse(connectionString))
    {
    }

    public RedisCacheConnectionPoolManager(int poolSize, ConfigurationOptions configurationOptions)
    {
        if (poolSize < MIN_CONNECTIONS || poolSize > MAX_CONNECTIONS) throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Pool size parameter must be within {0} and {1}.", MIN_CONNECTIONS.ToString(), MAX_CONNECTIONS.ToString()));
        if (configurationOptions == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(string.Format("Configuration Options parameter cannot be null."));

        _poolSize = poolSize;
        _configurationOptions = configurationOptions;

        Initialize();
    }

    // Destructor
    ~RedisCacheConnectionPoolManager()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public IConnectionMultiplexer GetConnection()
    {
        var loadedLazies = _connections.Where(x => x.IsValueCreated);

        if (loadedLazies.Count() == _connections.Count)
        {
            return _connections.OrderBy(x => x.Value.GetCounters().TotalOutstanding).First().Value;
        }

        return _connections.First(x => !x.IsValueCreated).Value;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        _connections = new ConcurrentBag<Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _poolSize; i++)
        {
            _connections.Add(new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(_configurationOptions)));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // free all managed resource
                    var activeConnections = _connections.Where(lazy => lazy.IsValueCreated).ToList();
                    activeConnections.ForEach(connection => connection.Value.Dispose());

                    while (!_connections.IsEmpty)
                    {
                        _connections.TryTake(out var taken);
                    }
                }
            }
            // free all unmanaged resources here
        }
        finally
        {
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}

public static class RedisClient()
{
    private static IRedisCacheConnectionPoolManager _connectionPoolManager;

    public static IConnectionMultiplexer GetConnnection()
    {
        return _connectionPoolManager.GetConnection();
    }   ​

   ​ private static IRedisCacheConnectionPoolManager GetConnectionPoolManager()
   ​ {
       ​if (_connectionPoolManager == null)
       ​{
           ​lock (_lock)
           ​{
              ​if (_connectionPoolManager == null 
               ​{

                try
                 ​​ {
                      ​​_connectionPoolManager = new RedisCacheConnectionPoolManager(config.PoolSize, config.Configuration);
                  ​​}
                  ​​catch (Exception ex)
                  ​​{
                      ​​// handle error and log
                  ​​}
              ​​}
          ​​}
      ​​}

      ​​return _connectionPoolManager;
  ​​}
```

Comment: 10_000 connections is an insanely huge amount. Normally, one would do this with 2 to 10 connections. If you are using some value anywhere near that 10k, AWS is probably telling you to stop creating so many connections